# MYSQL query to display away team name and home team name

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.
games includes Date, hteam, ateam, hscore, ascore.
teams includes id, tname.

This query:

```
SELECT
    games.DATE,
    teams.tname AS "Away",
    games.ascore AS "A Score",
    games.hteam AS "Home",
    games.hscore AS "H Score"
FROM
    games
INNER JOIN teams ON games.ateam = teams.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN teams AS t
ON
    games.hteam = t.tname
ORDER BY
    games.DATE ASC
```

ends up producing this output:

```
DATE Ascending 1        Away        A Score Home    H Score     
2008-01-01 20:00:00     Saxons      2       3       0
2008-01-01 20:00:00     Spurs       0       1       1
2008-01-08 20:00:00     Saxons      1       2       2
2008-01-08 20:00:00     Celtics     1       1       1
```

My question is how do I get the Home team displayed as its name, rather than its id so the output is:

```
DATE Ascending 1        Away        A Score Home        H Score     
2008-01-01 20:00:00     Saxons      2       Celtics     0
2008-01-01 20:00:00     Spurs       0       Wanderers   1
2008-01-08 20:00:00     Saxons      1       Spurs       2
2008-01-08 20:00:00     Celtics     1       Wanderers   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do another join with the "teams" table to get your result. 
So something along the lines of :

```
SELECT
    games.DATE,
    teams_away.tname AS "Away",
    games.ascore AS "A Score",
    teams_home.tname AS "Home",
    games.hscore AS "H Score"
FROM
    games
INNER JOIN teams teams_away ON games.ateam = teams_away.id
INNER JOIN teams teams_home ON games.hteam = teams_home.id
ORDER BY
    games.DATE ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to write the query using subqueries, which avoids joins:

```
SELECT
    games.DATE,
    (SELECT tname FROM teams WHERE teams.id = games.hteam) AS "Away",
    games.ascore AS "A Score",
    (SELECT tname FROM teams WHERE teams.id = games.ateam) AS "Home",
    games.hscore AS "H Score"
FROM
    games
ORDER BY
    games.DATE ASC
```

Comment: this solution reads better for me, but runs slightly slower than the recommendation above.